# PowerDesigner : Import table structure with columns and types with Excel

Tags: import, powerdesigner

I'm trying to find a way for import my structures in Powerdesigner with Excel.
There is an option for importing Excel file so it possible but noway...

I don't know how must be the Excel file, can I find a template somewhere ?
Have you ever success to import this kind of files or are  we forced to write manually each columns from each tables ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it, so I am not sure that my way is the **right** way...

Via `Model>Extensions>Attach An extension`, attach the Excel Import to your model.

You can now find `Excel Import File` in the contextual menu of your model in the Browser.

Here is my sample Excel file:

```
<Sheet1>
Name,Code
A,AA
B,BB
<Sheet2>
Name,Code,Table
C,CC,A
D,DD,B
E,EE,F
```

I launch `Excel Import File`, select my Excel file.

I import the table Sheet1 as Table, and use the default mapping Name to Name, and Code to Code...

I import the table Sheet2 as Table.Column, and use the default mappings Name to Name, Code to Code, Table to "Parent"

And I get these tables (I have also selected the Create Symbols in Active Diagram option).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the Model menu, go to (for instance) Tables, then you will see an Excel icon on the overview. Click that and it will allow you to export the list to Excel. The Excel export has the exact same format as your input needs to be in order to automatically map to the correct columns.