# PowerDesigner Import Table from Excel to create

Tags: powerdesigner

I have an Excel file with the following format:

- Column 1: Domain Name
- Column 2: Entity Name
- Column 3: Attribute Name
- Column 4: Data Type

I am using the "Excel import wizard" in PowerDesigner, and I am unsure about the selections I need to make after choosing the file.

- What should I select in the "Import Table as" list box? I want to ensure that the data is imported correctly.
- In the "Import Column Attribute List," what should I choose as the list of associated objects for each column, considering the format of my Excel file?

Any guidance or step-by-step instructions on the selections to make in these options would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The details in the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118562/powerdesigner-import-table-structure-with-columns-and-types-with-excel?rq=2) could help you. There are many explanations also in the Comment of the Excel Import extension.

You have to select **one class** to import **each sheet** from the Excel document.

Given your list of columns, you are importing "Entity.Entity Attribute" (in "Import table: Sheet1, As:").

- First column becomes a `Domain`
- Second column becomes a `<Parent>` (the object under which the Entity Attribute is attached)
- Third column becomes the `Name`
- Fourth column becomes the `Data Type`.

In my test, it nearly works, with just some error messages about the Data Type:

[image]

> Error: Could not set attribute DataType for Entity Attribute
> 'Employee.First name' with value 'A30' (Cannot set value 'A30' for
> attribute Data Type of Entity Attribute 'Employee.First name': Data
> Type cannot be set to this value)

[image]

Maybe it would be more efficient to have several sheets:

- first sheet: Domain (name, code, data type)
- second sheet: Data Item (name, code, data type, domain name)
- third sheet: Entity Attribute (entity, data item name)

EDIT: moved "domain name" from the third to the second sheet in the final suggestion.